# Error -bash: .: /usr/bin/[: cannot execute binary file on cygwin

Tags: bash, shell, cygwin

I was executing a script  to clone code from some local repository on my virtual system through cygwin prompt:

```
 mkdir CPM_WORKAREA
 touch ~/.ssh/config
 {
   echo "Host gerrit.epk.ericsson.se" 
   echo "   HostkeyAlgorithms ssh-dss" 
   echo " Hostname 136.225.198.208" 
   echo User $signumid
   echo "PubKeyAuthentication yes" 
   echo "IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa"
 } > ~/.ssh/config

 cd ~/CPM_WORKAREA
 git clone ssh://gerrit.epk.ericsson.se:29418/tools/devenv devenv.x
 git config --global user.email $1
 mkdir -p /proj/env
 ln -s /usr/bin /proj/env/bin
 cd
 if ! grep -q 'alias vi=vim' .bashrc  ; then
 {
   echo "alias vi=vim" >> .bashrc 
   echo 'export USER='$signumid'' >> .bashrc
   echo 'export         DEVENVHOME=${DEVENVHOME:-/home/'$signumid'/CPM_WORKAREA/devenv.x}' >> .bashrc
   echo '. $DEVENVHOME/sourceme.sh' >> .bashrc 
   }
 else
   {
   sed -i "s/.*USER.*/export USER=$signumid/
        s% .*DEVENVHOME=[$].*%             DEVENVHOME=\${DEVENVHOME:-/home/$signumid/CPM_WORKAREA/devenv.x}%" .bashrc
   }
 fi

  if ! grep -q 'EDITOR=vim' .bash_profile  ; then
  {
    echo "EDITOR=vim" >> .bash_profile
    echo "export EDITOR" >> .bash_profile
    echo '. [ -r $HOME/.bashrc ] && . $HOME/.bashrc' >> .bash_profile
  }
  fi

  touch .vimrc
  {
  echo "set nocp" 
  echo "syntax on"
  } > .vimrc
```

After executing this script, when i am closing the cygwin prompt and then opening it again, it shows :

```
   -bash: .: /usr/bin/[: cannot execute binary file
```

at the top of the cygwin prompt.

I saw some review that the error is due to executing the script on some wrong architecture.

So, I tried checking the `.bashrc` file to check out what changes are being made in the `.bashrc` file after the script is executed. But I could not figure out how the changes being made are leading to this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
echo '. [ -r $HOME/.bashrc ] && . $HOME/.bashrc' >> .bash_profile
```

This creates a profile that wants to "source the `[` command" (which is not a shell script, but a binary file). It looks like the `.` in `. [` shouldn't be there.

Comment: Yes, i figured out the error and it works fine now.Thanks.